# Bootstrap responsive to browser size but not in responsive inspect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I just built a website in which styles and layouts are responsive when adjusting browser window size, but when I open responsive inspect, it does not respond-- columns don't break at all and the window simply resizes into a percentage of the site...
Why would this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that you have Responsive Meta Tag inside your Head tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```